# Log In and Session Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to develop a website with Laravel for my finals, but it's getting a bit hard.

The thing is that I want to use a form to log in my database users and establish a session from it.

I made a form in my "main" view but I'm too newbie to find a solution. It looks like this:

Login Form :

[image]

I have no idea on how to do the controller neither the view or the routes, i'm a newbie in Laravel and we've done almost nothing significatively in class about this framework.

Thank you for your attention

Comment: Hi there. Welcome to SO. This is really not the site to get help in a tutorial manner. This is more like "This is what I want, this is what I tried, these are the errors/issues" type of place. I would like to suggest you take a look at this tutorial btw: https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-and-easy-laravel-login-authentication

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write your own controller for that. Laravel has built-in auth scaffolding, you just need to setup your database connection in .env file and use this command:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

This command will generate laravel auth scaffolding for you, than you can customize it for your project. It has login/register functionality already.
Laravel documentation explaining everything you need to do that task, just look at [this page.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#authentication-quickstart)

If you have no time for that you can watch this [auth tutorial.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fEOHPWeVZE&list=PL_UnIDIwT95PdM78SPaEiaS0fAdHsmvbQ&index=11)